# what's different between '".$string."' and '$string" on MySQL Querys

Tags: mysql

what's different between below two query's on `'".$string."'` and `'$string'`

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserName='".$USERNAME."' AND Pass='".$PASS."'
/* AND */
SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserName='$USERNAME' AND Pass='$PASS'
```

if different what's better for security ? *strings always secure on input but just for above differents*

**EDIT:**
I use above querys on PHP JUST and need it on it

Comment: Neither is good for security. Use `SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserName = @userName AND Pass = @pass` instead, with parameters `@userName` and `@pass`.

Comment: If those are double-quoted PHP strings, both are the same.

Comment: I edit it , yes I use it on PHP .

Comment: They are exactly the same to PHP... the top example would make sense if using single-quotes since it wouldn't parse the variables in that case, so they need to be concated to the string.

Comment: Except that the top example is clearly delimited by double quotes…

Comment: i suggest u use PDO or mysqli_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between them in your case.

But you'll see a difference if the string you're concatenating **does not contain special chars** (such as `'`) :

```
$b = 'b';
$string = "a" . $b . "c";
```

Is not equivalent to :

```
$b = 'b';
$string = "a$bc";
```

Because PHP will look for `$bc` variable. But this is equivalent to :

```
$b = 'b';
$string = "a{$b}c";
```

As well as your example is equivalent to :

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserName='{$USERNAME}' AND Pass='{$PASS}'
```

But take care, the single quotted string :

```
$b = 'b';
$string = 'a{$b}c';
```

will be litteraly read as `a{$b}c`.

Finally, as @duskwuff warns, you should be aware of [sql injections](http://bobby-tables.com/about.html).

Answer (score 3):

In PHP, at least, there is absolutely no difference between the two -- they do the exact same thing. Both are equally vulnerable to SQL injection.